AWS CDK Deploying Open API on Stage and retrofit and version management at stage level
My question is similar to this one AWS CDK Deploying to stage without deleting previous stages, but this does not talk about retrofit/changes or version management at API gateway . So raising a new question
I have build pipeline that runs CDK to set up the infra. The input to this pipeline is stageName , which is dev, sit, uat and prod.
Below is code to set up the api-gateway stack
  public readonly api: apigateway.SpecRestApi;
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    this.api = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, 'my-api', {
      deploy: false,
      apiDefinition: apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromAsset('path/to/swagger.yaml'),
    });

MyStack2 will have code to create stage and deployment. MyStack2  id will be appended with stage name like my-api-deployment-stack-{stageName}
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, api: apigateway.SpecRestApi, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

   const stageName = this.node.tryGetContext('stageName');

    const deployment = new apigateway.Deployment(this, `my-api-deployment`, { api });
    new apigateway.Stage(this, `my-api-stage`, {
        stageName,
        deployment,
    });

The above code will work well to promote the code from dev --> sit --> uat --> prod. But once the code is promoted to PROD, I need to work on next code version and need to update swagger on dev stage (assume a breaking change from prod swagger). How can one do deployment on dev without impacting PROD stage.
Reason for confusion is the APIGateway stack which has the swagger (yml) asset is not associated to any stage. How does AWS maintain different version of swaggers for each stage.
Please note : When my infra build pipeline runs with input parameter stage, both MyStack1 and MyStack2 are created.
